# Finding pdf for a random selection of dice.

Tags: probability

Random selection of dice, where the probability of rolling a '2', X for the dice is a random variable with pdf

$$
f_X(x) = ax 
$$
 for 0 < x < 1, and zero otherwise. Find a.

I am not sure how to approach this, as I do not know if the dice are fair, and do not know what the pdf distribution would be, and don't understand how one would find a constant from the given information.

Comment: I also find the problem puzzling. The dice are not fair, and we are not told the overall probability of tossing a 2.  I do not see how to compute $a$.

Comment: On the bright side, I'm glad it isn't just me. I would just assume a fair probability to see if that would give me insight into how to approach the problem, but later parts of the problem indicate that the dice are not fair.

Comment: I think the interpretation of Titus is a reasonable one, and the only one for which one can produce an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a theory, despite the awkward wording of the question.  Suppose you have a barrel full of dice, and each one has a different probability of rolling a 2.  You pick one of the dice at random - then $P($the die will roll a $2) = X$ is a random variable.

The problem statement suggests that this is a continuous random variable and that the density is given by $f_X(x) = ax$.  I.e. if I pick a single die, the probability that it is a die which comes up as a 2 between $x$ and $x+dx$ percent of the time is roughly $ax$.  We want to know $a$.

The calculation is straightforward, regardless of the setting; given a probability density function $f_X$, we know 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) dx = 1. $$
Use this fact to deduce $a$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it was the wording of the problem where I wasn't really sure of what was going on. The way you described the set up really helped!